# Yii not able to load models from generated modules

Tags: yii, model, module

I have created a calendar module. I then created a model for Events and also generated the files for crud operations. But when i copied it to their respective directories in the calendar module, it is not working as Yii is not able to find the model class Events. Though when I place the Events model file into the main models directory it starts working. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your config/main file to include the models from your new module
with something like this

```
.....
'import' => array(
    application.modules.calendar.models.*
 ),
```